# OpenCV build an image with pixel Pointer

Tags: c++, image, opencv, pointers

I'm trying to implement an OpenCV program into an existing program. In this program an image is captured by a camera and I can access this image by a pointer which points at the first pixel of the image.
My question is now, how could I build an image out of the information (Pointer to the first pixel, width and heigth of the image) with which OpenCV can work with.

I hope my problem is clear enough descriped.

Do you have any idea?

```
     cv::Mat aCameraImage = cv::Mat(cv::Size(getImageWidth(), getImageHeight()), CV_8UC1, getImageDataPtr());

     if (!aCameraImage.empty())
     {
       cv::imshow("Camera Image", aCameraImage);
       cv::waitKey(100);
     }

     for(int i = 0; i<aCameraImage.cols; i++ )
     {
        for(int j = 0; j<aCameraImage.rows; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << aCameraImage.at<uchar>(i,j) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
     }
```

Comment: cv::Mat has a constructor that accepts external data. Use cv::Mat(cv::Size(width, height), yourPixelType, pointerToYourData); where yourPixelType is most probably CV_8UC3 if your image is a 8 bit RGB or BGR image without alpha channel.

Comment: if there is an additional padding at the end of each row (often this is used for optimization), there is another constructor for that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick respones!!! So now I get an Mat which is obviously not empty. But My image is all black :-/

Comment: But I think thats a problem with my code. So Thank you for the solution :-)

Comment: what kind of pointer did you get from your camera? is it `unsigned char*` or something different?!?

Comment: Yes its an unsigned char*

Comment: is it a color image? if you print the values to terminal/console before using openCV, are they all close to 0?

Comment: When I try this:

Comment: The values aren't 0 :-/ any idea?

Comment: can you edit your code to the question text? At least you have to swap i a j here

Comment: I added the code to the question. Have no idea why the image is black :-/

Comment: atm you are assuming a single-channel image, is that right? You'll have to change i and j, but that won't fix the 0s. Change it this way: `for(int j = 0; j<aCameraImage.rows; j++ ) { for(int i = 0; i<aCameraImage.cols; i++ ) {std::cout << aCameraImage.at<uchar>(j,i) << " ";} std::cout << std::endl; }` it will prevent from accessing out-of-image values for non-quadratic images and will be more efficient because of the order. Again: Should your image be a color image or a grayscale image (provided by the camera)?

Comment: the image should be a grayscale image. I get the image from a monochrome camera

Comment: can you tell me what camera it is? Do you know the possible range of values? Any code samples on how to access the values natively? Often data is provided by a `unsigned char` Pointer, but the real data might still be something else (that has to be type-casted). Might the values the float type or 32 bit integer or 16 bit integer? Can you just try `CV_16SC1` `CV_16UC1` `CV_32SC1` `CV_32FC1` `CV_64FC1`? Probably the code will crash for some of the types, but maybe you'll find the right one within those...

Comment: so i don't have the code for the camera access. I just get the Pointer :-/

Comment: camera is an eco285mvge

Comment: I tried it with all types. The result was a noiesy image when the type was CV_32FC1. When I put my hand under the cam it starts to get more noisy

Comment: you should contact the manufacturer and get all information about the generated images (memory layout etc.) and how to access them. Where did you get the pointer from? Any API or SDK or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an SDK, I guess you are using it. 
Do you create such a structure?

```
IMAGE_INFO *ImageInfo = new IMAGE_INFO; 
ImageInfo->ImageData  = Image_getDataPointer(Image); 
ImageInfo->SizeX      = Image_getSizeX(Image); 
ImageInfo->SizeY      = Image_getSizeY(Image); 
ImageInfo->PixelType  = Image_getPixelType(Image); 
ImageInfo->ImageID    = Image_getImageID(Image);
```

The SDK says that the camera might deliver 12 bit encoded images. Please check `PixelType` and tell me what it is.

```
enum   GVSP_PIXEL_TYPE { 
   GVSP_PIX_UNKNOWN = 0x0000, 
   GVSP_PIX_MONO8 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY8BIT | 0x0001),
   GVSP_PIX_MONO10 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY16BIT | 0x0003), 
   GVSP_PIX_MONO10_PACKED = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY12BIT | 0x0004), 
   GVSP_PIX_MONO12 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY16BIT | 0x0005),
   GVSP_PIX_MONO12_PACKED = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY12BIT | 0x0006), 
   GVSP_PIX_MONO16 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY16BIT | 0x0007), 
   GVSP_PIX_BAYGR8 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY8BIT | 0x0008), 
   GVSP_PIX_BAYRG8 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY8BIT | 0x0009), 
   GVSP_PIX_BAYGB8 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY8BIT | 0x000A),
   GVSP_PIX_BAYBG8 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY8BIT | 0x000B), 
   GVSP_PIX_BAYGR10 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY16BIT | 0x000C),
   GVSP_PIX_BAYRG10 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY16BIT | 0x000D), 
   GVSP_PIX_BAYGB10 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY16BIT | 0x000E), 
   GVSP_PIX_BAYBG10 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY16BIT | 0x000F), 
   GVSP_PIX_BAYGR12 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY16BIT | 0x0010), 
   GVSP_PIX_BAYRG12 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY16BIT | 0x0011), 
   GVSP_PIX_BAYGB12 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY16BIT | 0x0012), 
   GVSP_PIX_BAYBG12 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY16BIT | 0x0013), 
   GVSP_PIX_RGB24 = (GVSP_PIX_RGB | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY24BIT), 
   GVSP_PIX_GRAY8 = (GVSP_PIX_MONO | GVSP_PIX_OCCUPY8BIT) 
 }
```

You can use some provided functions to convert the image:

```
Image_getImage12bitAs8bit(Camera, Buffer8bit, BufferLength); 
Image_getImage12bitAs16bit(Camera, Buffer16bit, BufferLength); 
//Image_getImage16bitAs8bit(Camera, Buffer8bit, BufferLength);
```

afterwards you can maybe use `CV_8UC1` or `CV_16UC1`

Can you further provide the results of those functions?

- StreamingChannel_getPixelType()
- StreamingChannel_getBufferData()
- StreamingChannel_getBufferSize()
- StreamingChannel_getImagePitch()
- StreamingChannel_getImageSizeX()
- StreamingChannel_getImageSizeY()

Comment: oh thank you very much for your help!!! So my PixelType is GVSP_PIX_MONO8

Comment: Camera_getPitch():    1392

Comment: Camera_getSizeX(): 1392

Comment: Camera_getSizeY():  1040

Comment: So when PixelType = GVSP_PIX_MONO8 CV_8UC1 should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: OK now I runs :-) I still got an error with the image width an heigth. The rigth type was CV_8UC1.

Comment: In the existing program there where different variables with the name Heigth and Width and stupidly I took the wrong one :-/

Comment: now everthing works perfectly. Just one more time ;-) : thank you very much for the help!!!

Comment: nice to hear that I could help. Have fun :)

Comment: You definitely did :-) Thanks ;-)